# Example of how to write Django Test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have to write some tests for some services I build that connect our backend to a mobile app another team member is building. I was asked to write some unit tests once I finished them. I am not familiar with Django testing so I wanted to ask if someone could give me an example of how you would test one of the services. That way I can then learn by example and do the rest on my own?

This is one example of a service I built that finds if there is a user by that email in our database and return a json object:

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_find(request):
    args = json.loads(request.body, object_hook=utils._datetime_decoder)
    providedEmail = args['providedEmail']
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=providedEmail)
        user_dict = {'exists': 'true', 'name': user.first_name, 'id': user.id}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(user_dict))
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user_dict = {'exists': 'false'} 
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(user_dict))
```

What would be the correct way to test something like this? I am guessing I have to mimic a request somehow that gives me an email and then have two tests where one matches and one doesn't match an existing user and make sure each returns the appropriate object. Is this the correct way of thinking about it? Can someone help me out a bit with the syntax? I'm guessing using django.test.Client in some way would be appropriate?

Answer (score -1):

What you need to test is if your code can not be broken. That means your code should always give a response and not generate any error in any case.

Since if the things you can test are-

1) authorization- is service accessible by any user or only authenticated ones, if only authenticated then test response for both kind of users, anonymous and authenticated. While testing response, test that you get 401 for anonymous users and 200 for authenticated ones.

2) response for non existing emails

3) response for users without a first_name if first_name is optional.

4) response data in case of valid request- is data received of correct user

There may be more tests, these from top of my head.

Comment: *"your code should always give a response and not generate any error in any case"* - that's not accurate. It would be perfectly reasonable, for example, to expect that a malformed request (e.g. one that didn't contain the `providedEmail`) would result in an exception of some kind that the caller would be responsible for handling.

Comment: @jonrsharpe- yes it would, i just gave an overview of what tests may consist of.